# Node.js access var issue

Tags: javascript, node.js

My project structure is the following:

```
project
   - js
      - *.js
app.js
```

In my `app.js`, I define a config variable this way:

```
try {
    var config = yaml.load(program.config);
} catch (e) {
    console.error('unable to load configuration, Error:', e.message);
    process.exit(1)
}
```

Which works. 
I now would like to access to the content of the var in `project/js/*.js`, but I got `config is undefined`. 
Why? Isn't `config` not supposed to be accessible everywhere?

** EDIT **

My code in `*.js`:

```
var fetchMail = function() {

    console.log(config); // config undefined
    // Other stuff
};
```

And how I export my code in `app.js`: `export.config = config`. And then require it in `*.js`: `var app = require(../app);`

Comment: Did you export the config in app.js???

Comment: Edit: Too fast. Does not work. `export.config = config`

Comment: Unfortunately, no :( (same issue `config is undefined`)

Comment: Can you post the full code??

Comment: Done, see my edit.

Comment: post the code how you exported and how you required that in other file all those lines..

Comment: Done in the new edit!

Answer (score 0):

I assume you need to change 
`export.config = config` to `exports.default = config`.

If you are exporting something else than `exports.config = config`.

In other file you need either

```
import { config } from ..
```

or

`var config = require(...).config;`

Answer (score 0):

You should put `var config = null` on top of `try` and you than can access the config variable. Initializing `var` inside try will create the variable inside that scope. Therefore, you can't be accessing config variable.